# Where is Ruby code compiled when using javascript HotRuby.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'd like to understand the interaction of Ruby and Javascript [running on this web page](http://hotruby.yukoba.jp/test-web/Box2DFlashAS3.html), that exposes HotRuby.js

I understand clearly that HotRuby is just the VM.

But where is the Ruby code compiled to YARV ?

Would it be simple to extend such a site to write our own code in the browser and run it on HotRuby ? (a bit like in incredible [Amber Smalltalk](http://amber-lang.net/))

Comment: Actually that's running inside of the Flash runtime. ActionScript is similar to JavaScript, but not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on [John Resig's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/ruby-vm-in-javascript/) (last visited october 1 2013)

Here is a copy of the author's note, that delivers the subtance of the trick :

> Script finds  tags and extracts the inline Ruby code from them.
>       The Ruby code is sent to the server via an XMLHttpRequest.
>       The server-side CGI script (in Ruby, using Ruby 1.9) compiles the incoming Ruby into its associated opcodes and serializes it into a JSON data structure.
>       The browser consumes the opcodes, translating it into JavaScript, and executes it.

Comment: -1 for now: I'm glad to change it to a +1 for even just a single sentence explaining what the article says, please.